# WebForm project to MVC - missing context menu items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, episerver

I have a significant webform project that needs MVC4 integrated into it. MVC controllers etc.. are working fine. However i am not getting the MVC type context menu items e.g. add view when right click a controller method (see below - this is the add view that I want to see. It is missing from my project).

[image]

I have tried creating a blank MVC project then swapping out the web form csproj file for this and readding in all the webform elements but it broke the site in all manner of ways that i don't have time to resolve. I really don't want to go down this rabbit hole in any case - i suspect it's the wrong approach.

I have tried adding in (what i believe to be) the correct projecttype guid into the csprojj file by editing with a text editor i.e.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};
{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

becomes

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

but i still do not get the correct context menu items.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Many Thanks for all help

**Edit**

This link gives an example for MVC3 and gives an idea of what I am trying to achieve. But the project type guid crashes the site (because it is MVC3) and my own efforts aren't working

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html

**Further details i think are probably irrelevant**

The project is an install of EPiServer Relate+ 7. A new site is starting from this but the majority of the site itself will be MVC (i hope). But we will use the re-existing web form elements for community type pages. There is no time or budget to convert these.

I don't think this is relevant to the solution. I think the problem is generic rather than particular to EPiServer.

Comment: I can see the Add View in the screen shot. What are you referring to?

Comment: the add view is what is missing - this is taken from a vanilla MVC project that works. Will edit to clarify

Comment: I agree, that the question is pretty blurry... How exactly are you having MVC is working together with webforms? That usually is not so easy way.

Comment: If you want to have all the features from MVC project, you must have MVC project. Possibly, to have webforms and MVC (views/formatting capabilities) together, you must try to use MVC5, but still, you must have MVC project created.

Comment: it's an install of EPiServer Relate+ 7. This is webforms when it is installed. But MVC can still be used if the Mvc dll is referenced. This is why there is a need for the hybrid. The orignal install has a proj type of web forms but I want to convert it so it recognises the MVC context menu.

Comment: sorry - the frame of the question is that there is a webform project that needs MVC context in - this link give an indication of what I am trtying to achieve http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html. Telling me to use an MVC project type isn't really what I am asking (the CMS element gives an indication of why i am doing this). I appreciate the help but it's not going to get me where I need to be. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embarrassing!!!

I nearly got this right. I just needed to restart Visual Studio  when I changed the project type Guid

So - the project type Guid for MVC4 is

```
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
```

and the full element is

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

BUT - don't forget to restart Visual Studio (Doh!!!)

I'll keep this question up in case others have got the same problem

Thanks for everyone's time